# plot multiple dependence data in one graph in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm trying to plot on Julia, here is the sample data [Ecdat Airline](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/doc/Ecdat/Airline.html). I want to compare the airline 1~6's cost, but the x-axis was wrong(should be 1970-1984), and my code seems too dirty, maybe it could be plot in one line.

```
using Plots, UnicodePlots, RDatasets
unicodeplots()
v = dataset("Ecdat","Airline")
plot(v.Cost[v.Airline .== 1])
plot!(v.Cost[v.Airline .== 2])
plot!(v.Cost[v.Airline .== 3])
plot!(v.Cost[v.Airline .== 4])
plot!(v.Cost[v.Airline .== 5])
plot!(v.Cost[v.Airline .== 6])
```

The output

```
                      ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
         4.88870026e6 │⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠄⠀│ y1
                      │⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡠⠔⠁⠀⠀│ y2
                      │⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠤⠊⠀⠀⣀⠄⠀│ y3
                      │⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⣀⠤⠔⠊⠁⣀⠤⠒⠉⠀⠀⠀│ y4
                      │⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡠⠒⠒⠊⠉⠉⠀⢀⣀⠤⠒⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│ y5
                      │⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡠⠊⠀⠀⠀⠀⡠⠒⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│ y6
                      │⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠔⠁⠀⠀⢀⠔⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡰⠁⠀⠀⢀⠎⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡠⠊⠀⠀⢀⠔⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠤⠊⠁⠀⠀⡠⠊⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⡠⠔⠊⠁⠀⠀⠀⡠⠊⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣀⠤⠒⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡠⠔⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣀⠤⠤⠒⠊⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⡠⠔⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⠤⠔⠒⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣀⠤⠔⠊⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⡀⠀│
                      │⠀⠀⠀⢀⣀⣀⡠⠤⠤⠒⠊⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⡠⠤⠒⠊⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣀⡠⠤⣤⣒⣒⣉⣁⡀⠀│
                      │⠀⠈⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⡠⠔⠒⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣀⡠⠤⠔⣒⡲⠮⠛⠛⠉⠓⠊⠉⠉⠀⠀⠀⢀⣀⠄⠀│
                      │⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣀⡠⠤⠒⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣀⡠⠤⠔⠒⠊⠉⣁⡠⠔⠒⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⡠⠤⠒⠊⠁⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⠐⠒⠒⠉⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣀⣀⣀⠤⠤⠤⠤⠒⠒⣒⣊⣉⣉⣁⠤⠤⠤⠔⠒⠊⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⣀⣠⡤⠤⠴⠶⠮⠭⠔⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠂⠀│
                      │⠀⠠⠤⠤⠔⠒⣒⣒⣒⡲⠶⠶⠮⠛⠛⠛⠓⠒⠒⠊⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⣉⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣤⣤⣤⣔⡲⠶⠮⠛⠛⠋⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
   -71402.26000000001 │⠤⠼⠿⠿⠿⠿⠶⠶⠶⠶⠶⠶⠶⠾⠿⠿⠿⠭⠭⠭⠭⠭⠭⠭⠭⠭⠭⠭⠭⠭⠭⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤│
                      └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
                      0.5800000000000001                                       15.42
```

Comment: See "DataFrames support" here
http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/input_data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot DataFrames, use StatsPlots rather than Plots (it's an extension of Plots to DataFrames and statistical types). Also you don't need to import UnicodePlots directly. Finally, you're looking for the `group` keyword.
Your code should be

```
using StatsPlots, RDatasets
unicodeplots()
v = dataset("Ecdat","Airline")
@df v plot(:Year, :Cost, group = :Airline)
```

Comment: The output picture is different from the result, it can't not compare different airline's relative cost

Comment: @DanielYCLin Yeah, to get the plot you were after we also need to include the x axis variable, year. I've edited the answer.